# Insert a string into a different program?

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that runs the checked items from a ListView control. These items are self-extracting ZIP .EXE files. Unfortunately, I want them encrypted, and it doesn't seem like WinZip lets you pass the password as a parameter. This means, the user has to input the password (they're all the same for all the .EXE files) over and over again.

```
Try
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then

        If Directory.Exists(TextBox1.Text) Then
            ' Process.Start(tmpWhatRun, "/auto " & TextBox1.Text)


            Dim startInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
            Dim pStart As New System.Diagnostics.Process

            startInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(tmpWhatRun, _
               "/auto " & TextBox1.Text)
            pStart.StartInfo = startInfo
            pStart.Start()
            pStart.WaitForExit()

        Else : MsgBox("Invalid directory.")
        End If

    Else
        Dim startInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        Dim pStart As New System.Diagnostics.Process

        startInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(tmpWhatRun)
        pStart.StartInfo = startInfo
        pStart.Start()
        pStart.WaitForExit()     
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

I've seen some stuff about using Windows APIs but that seems like it could cause some problems since these are external programs not owned by my program.

Comment: depending on the application's tos, you can use their api's as a part of a commercial application as long as you have purchased a commercial copy of the application. This may or may not help you out, just a tidbit of information.

Comment: O mamma mia, your code is orrible, you use TextBox1.Text everywhere instead of reading it once and you hide the exception without anything in the catch... brrrrrr! :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use 7zip or zlib for extracting your exe. 
They come with .Net examples

Comment: They can handle .EXE files created by WinZip with AES256? I'd imagine I"d have to bundle the portable version then, since the entire point is our clients may not have WinZip or something similar, and we don't want them to have to install anything. Thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Jai, there are command line extensions for WinZip if you really want to use it, or you can try to do the same with WinRar.